# Add .json extension to a Stream outputBlob in blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The following code will create a file in a container on my Azure Storage Account.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, Stream outputBlob)
{  
   log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
   using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body)) {

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody);
        await outputBlob.WriteAsync(bytes);
        return (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult("ok");

     }
}
```

[image]

The outputBlob is pointing to the StorageAccount.
My question is: How do I add an .json extension to the filename?

Comment: Are you using AzureBlobStorage Class?  You can try the method described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198544/write-stream-async-to-azure-blobstorage

Comment: Can you edit your question share your complete code? How are you creating `outputBlob` in your code.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/10040559/2490286 ? Besides that you need to physically name your file with a .json extension

Comment: I hve updated the question, maybe you have some pointers?